# customization of tool tip in MS-CRM 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am new to MS-Crm. having lots of question regarding its customization.

1. how to edit its form.
2. how to edit tool tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a form in CRM:

Settings -> Customization -> Customize Entities -> Double-click entity to open it -> Forms and Views -> Double-click Form to open it.

You can change a tooltip of a form attribute (ie. a field) but it requires JavaScript in the onLoad event of the form.  There are plenty of examples if you Google, e.g.:

http://crm.atechnisch.nl/2009/07/use-tooltips-as-hot-help/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by how to edit its form.  To edit the onload/onsave/onchange scripts you need to go to Settings>Customization>Customize Entities>The entity to customize.

There is no supported way to add tooltips.  You'll most likely need to create your own tooltip code for fields and such and have it be loaded within the global.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Tool Tip solution here http://www.crmInnovation.com/inline_help.asp

BTW, you cannot edit CRM forms except through the customization wizard built into the system.